# Create a DoubleBinding with a constant value

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx, javabeans

In the following, is there a better way to initialize `acc`?

```
// . . .
private DoubleBinding acc = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0).add(0);

public void append(ObservableDoubleValue delta){
    // . . .
    acc = acc.add(delta);
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you wish to have a `DoubleBinding` and not an `ObservableDoubleValue` for example?

Comment: What do you mean by constant value? Anyway use ReadOnlyDoubleProperty or ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper based on your requirements. See the javadocs.

Comment: @sillyfly I just liked the fluent API (`acc.add(delta)`) better (than `Bindings.add(acc,delta)`). Not sure whether they have the same efficiency for updates.

Comment: @UlukBiy Look at `acc`'s type. It can't be `set` anyway. I just need a `DoubleBinding` whose value will always be a compile-time-given number.

Comment: Another way is to change `DoubleBinding` to `DoubleExpression`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `DoubleBinding` with the utilities in the [`Bindings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) class ([`createDoubleBinding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createDoubleBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-)):

```
private DoubleBinding acc = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> 0d);
```

The argument is a function that returns the value of the binding. In this case, and assuming Java 8, the function returns the constant value 0. Do note that this `DoubleBinding` won't be bound to any `Observable`.